# Show that $q$ is continuous

Tags: calculus

\begin{align}
q(t,\tau)=2\frac{x'(t)\cdot [x(\tau)-x(t)]}{|x(t)-x(\tau)|^2}-\cot \frac{\tau-t}{2}, \quad t\neq \tau
\end{align}
$x$ is class of $C^2$
In the book it is written it is continuous but I don't understand why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $x$ being of class $C^2$ ensures that $x'(t)$ is continuous. Now, $cot \frac{t-\tau}{2}$ is obviously continuous, so we look for the first part. There we can transform:

$2 \frac{x'(t)}{|x(t) - x(\tau)|}$

We need to show that this is continuous. Well,

Theorem 1: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous in set $S$ if and only if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are, and $g(x) \neq 0$ for each $x \in S$.

Using this theorem and using $x(t) \neq x(\tau)$ we have the claim.

Well, if $x(t)= x(\tau)$, then we have to cope with definability problem. So, he got to exclude that possibility, as in that case, function is not well-defined....

Comment: when $t \to \tau , \cot(\frac{t-\tau}{2}) $ is not continuous

Comment: which is  why $t$ and $\tau$ are mutually independent! When you put $g(t, \tau)$ there is no relationship between the two  arguments!

Comment: Ok i understand but i want to know what happens when $t =\tau $.